# How to update rows based on a select result on another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables as follow.

```
table contents -- stores content information.
+----+----------+----------+
| id |  name    |status    |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | content_1|0         |
|  2 | content_2|0         |
|  3 | content_3|0         |
+----+----------+----------+

table clusters -- stores cluster information
+----+----------+
| id |  name    |
+----+----------+
|  1 | cluster_1|
|  2 | cluster_2|
+----+----------+

table content_cluster -- each record indicates that one content is on one cluster
+----------+----------+-------------------+
|content_id|cluster_id|   last_update_date|
+----------+----------+-------------------+
|        1 |        1 |2020-10-01T11:30:00|
|        2 |        2 |2020-10-01T11:30:00|
|        3 |        1 |2020-10-01T10:30:00|
|        3 |        2 |2020-10-01T10:30:00|
+----------+----------+-------------------+
```

I want to update content status to 1 if a content's count in content_cluster table equals to the count of records in clusters. In other word, I want to combine following queries into one.

```
# get the count of clusters
# I note it as <cluster_count>
SELECT COUNT(cluster_id)
FROM clusters;

# get the contents whose record number in content_cluster equals to <cluster_count>;
# I note this list as <content_id_list>
SELECT content_id 
FROM content_cluster
GROUP BY content_id
HAVING COUNT(cluster_id)=<cluster_count>;

# update contents table
UPDATE contents
SET contents.status=1
WHERE content_id IN <content_id_list>
```

What should I do? I'm using MySQL.

I also want to delete the records from contents if content_id is not in content_cluster. please help!

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there just combine the individual codes. Before updating make sure that you are getting correct result by doing a `select` query

```
UPDATE contents
SET contents.status=1
WHERE content_id IN (SELECT content_id 
    FROM content_cluster
    GROUP BY content_id
    HAVING COUNT(cluster_id)=
    (SELECT COUNT(cluster_id) FROM clusters)
)
```